# Relationship with ADO.NET and Mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

In the database I have two tables, one student and another student address. They have a one-to-one relationship (1: 1).

[image]

When I use ado.net, with EF Designer From DataBase, visual studio understands relationship as one for many (1: n).

[image]

[image]
Entity student, code:

```
public partial class student
    {
        public student()
        {
            this.studentadress = new HashSet<studentadress>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<studentadress> studentadress { get; set; }
    }
```

How do I make him understand, and maintain the relationship of (1: 1). And without it creating a collection attribute in the entity, but an object attribute.